# Reusing script in multiple elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have piece of code showing radial bar as in this minimal working example:

http://codepen.io/shankarcabus/pen/GzAfb

I would like to insert several divs with this code, but the JS script remembers only the first value and places them everywhere where "percent" is used. Is there any nice, clean way to fix bar value in multiple cases?

JS code:

```
$(function(){
    var $ppc = $('.progress-pie-chart'),
    percent = parseInt($ppc.data('percent')),
    deg = 360*percent/100;
    if (percent > 50) {
        $ppc.addClass('gt-50');
    }
    $('.ppc-progress-fill').css('transform','rotate('+ deg +'deg)');
    $('.ppc-percents span').html(percent+'%');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$(function(){
    var $ppc = $('.progress-pie-chart');
    var percent;
    $ppc.each(function(){
        percent = parseInt($(this).data('percent'));
        deg = 360*percent/100;
        if (percent > 50) {
            $(this).addClass('gt-50');
        }
        $(this).find('.ppc-progress-fill').css('transform','rotate('+ deg +'deg)');
        $(this).find('.ppc-percents span').html(percent+'%');
    });



});
```

The `.each()` will do the changes for each `.progress-pie-chart` individually, and base it on the percent it calculates for that particular chart, rather than just using the first one's percent for all of them

Answer (score 2):

You should do it for each `.progress-pie-chart` element. . http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WvWaYB

```
$(function(){
  var $ppc = $('.progress-pie-chart');
  for(var i = $ppc.length; i --; ) {
      var el = $ppc[i],    
      percent = parseInt($(el).data('percent')),
      deg = 360*percent/100;
      if (percent > 50) {
        $(el).addClass('gt-50');
      }
      $(el).find('.ppc-progress-fill').css('transform','rotate('+ deg +'deg)');
      $(el).find('.ppc-percents span').html(percent+'%');
    }     
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Then you have to loop through each `.progress-pie-chart` element use `each()`. Try this:

```
  var percent;
  $('.progress-pie-chart').each(function(){
        percent = parseInt($(this).data('percent'));
        deg = 360*percent/100;
        if (percent > 50) {
            $(this).addClass('gt-50');
        }
        $(this).find('.ppc-progress-fill').css('transform','rotate('+ deg +'deg)');
        $(this).find('.ppc-percents span').html(percent+'%');
    });
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RPOeEy) with multiple charts.

Comment: That's what i had in mind. Works like a charm. Thank you.